# how do i use for-each in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

ok I am trying to print every element under ancient_wonders/wonder that is equal to name but when I do this:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="ancient_wonders/wonder">
     <xsl:value-of select="./name"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

it only prints te first element equal to name. here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="02-03.xsl"?>
<ancient_wonders>
 <wonder>
    <location>
        Rhodes, Greece
    </location>

    <name language="English">
        Christ of Brasil
    </name>
    <name language="English">
        Colossus of Rhodes
    </name>
    <name language="Chinese">
        Great Wall of China
    </name>
</wonder>
```

can someone explain to me how to do this.

Comment: No wonder, you only have one `wonder` element. You're iterating over the single wonder and returning the first `name` element within it. Frankly, I find `for-each` counter-intuitive in a declarative language that XSLT is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one **wonder** element in your XML, but multiple **name** elements. You **xsl:for-each** is looping over the **wonder** elements, and so will only iterate once. If you want to output the **name** elements, iterate over these....

```
<xsl:for-each select="ancient_wonders/wonder/name">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Or perhaps, if you do have more than one **wonder** for example, you can use a nested **xsl:for-each**

```
<xsl:for-each select="ancient_wonders/wonder">
    Location: <xsl:value-of select="location" />
    <xsl:for-each select="name">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: ok that I understand now. I thought that the for-each work a different way. thank you for your answer. but now im trying to print every name with language equal English and it wont work this is what im doing: <xsl:if test="name[@language='English']">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:if>